# How to get data from a local JSON file with fetch

Tags: javascript, json, file, fetch

I reckon this might be an old topic but I begin with Javascript...
I get this error in my Javascript base code   :
"Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/Users[...]data.json. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request"

All the answers I see online says that a local server is needed to use fetch with a file. But I would need to find solutions without using a local server.

Here is my code :

function getData() {

```
fetch('data.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
```

};

getData();

My files HTML et JS are well linked and my file data.json is located in the same folder.

Somebody (who has understood my problem :) could give me some help/advice please?
Thanks

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local

Answer (score 0):

It is not very wise to make that decision if you can avoid it, but there are different free websites that you could use in the same exact way, for example [extendsclass.com](https://extendsclass.com/) has a free json server that you can use to make your own server. All you have to do is make an account and send a fetch request to the api that they give you (with a limit of 10,000 request per month).